# calculating percentage based on values of other rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, hive

I have below query for which i am not able to frame a appropriate tile .
However here is my problem.

```
prv    pat id   flg
001    a        SIU
002    b        OVR
003    c        NULL
004    a        NULL
004    c        NULL
001    e        SIU
005    c        SIU   
005    f        SIU
```

expected output

```
prv          percentage
004          100%
003          100%
002          0%
```

The logic here is 
004 prv has 2 patid i.e

```
004    a        NULL
004    c        NULL
```

But patid "a" of 004 belongs to 001 "a" for which flg is SIU ,and "c" of 004 belongs to 005 "c" for which flag is SIU.
so percentage should 100 %,because both patid of 004 is SIU in other rows.

similaryly for 003 ,there is 1 row

```
003    c        NULL
```

here percentage is 100% ,because "c" of 003 patid belongs to 005 which has SIU flag,so for 003 its 100%

we will not calculate for 001 and 005 ,because they already have patid with SIU.

Link for sqlfiddle
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbd32/6/0

Comment: What a hell are you doing? :D

Comment: does it matter flag is SIU or OVR? or just having null value and not null value?

Comment: Also it's strange 004 second patid c also belongs to 005 like 003 case, with flag siu so why it's 50% in 004 case and 100 in 003?

Comment: Are you using Hive or MySQL?  Please tag correctly.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili  flag should be SIU or Non SIU(OVR,NULL etc). Regarding second question its 50% because 004 has 2 patid of which 1 is SIU in 005 prv ,c also exist for 003 as NULL,but we can ignore that because c has one field with SIU .

Comment: yes but for 004 as I said a has siu for 001 and same for c with 005 so why 50% still stays unclear for me, when for 003 it's 100%

Comment: @GordonLinoff it can solved in both mysql or hive query,any thing is fine.

Comment: No clue, what are trying :P

Comment: @ its 100% for 003 because c has only 1 patid c ,and this patid c has flag SIU in prv 005

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili sorry,for 004 it should 100% as well,How can i edit the question?

Comment: Okay last question: don't you want also countings for 002? cuz it's flag is not siu

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili , Yes,i didnt include this in output query.My mistake.it will be 0%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your final query should be (working, tested):

```
SELECT 
    main.prv,
    CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(pat_is_siu)/COUNT(*) * 100),'%') AS percentage
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.*,
        IFNULL((SELECT 1 FROM a AS b WHERE b.`flg` = "SIU" AND b.`pat` = a.`pat` LIMIT 1),0) AS pat_is_siu
    FROM a
    WHERE IFNULL(a.`flg`, "") != "SIU"
) main
GROUP BY main.`prv`
```

Comment: please don't run this on sqlfiddle as it goes on time out

Comment: ,Thank you so much :) .I will execute it against bigger data set and see

Comment: OKay so in that case please add indexes to columns, also if you want better precise results you should expand rounding with 2 decimals like that: `ROUND(SUM(pat_is_siu)/COUNT(*) * 100, 2)` - adding `, 2`

Comment: Hi george,Can you pleae explain the logic behind the this part of the query.  SELECT a.*,(SELECT 1 FROM a AS b WHERE b.flg = "SIU" AND
b.pat = a.pat ) AS pat_is_siu
    FROM a
    WHERE IFNULL(a.flg, "") != "SIU"  . Actually i am not aware to this type of syntax in select statement where you used  SELECT 1 FROM a AS b WHERE b.flg = "SIU" AND
b.pat = a.pat

Comment: Hello @Abid, sure I'll. It's called subquery in sql syntax, and it's to check if pat id is assigned with siu flag to any other entries in the table. 1st we select all entries which has not siu flag, and for each row we do the above logic I've just talked about

Comment: Thanks for explanation,Subquery as far as i know are associated after the where clause unlike here where you used directly in select clause.So ,that was the confusion for me?

Comment: you can use subquery in any part of the query, where you need it: in select statement, in joins, in grouping, in wheres etc..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120568/discussion-between-abid-and-george-garchagudashvili).

Answer (score 0):

**you may try below query:**

select 100/count(pat id) from table where flg<>'SIU' group by prv